# Sublime Text Plugin Open file symbol

Tags: sublime-text-plugin

I was trying to execute a command to open a file at the line of a text symbol. 
I tried to achieve that using the *show_overlay* command, but it will not open correctly if you try to use the ‘#’ in the search.

Example. create a project that contains a file,

**app/code/community/MagicToolbox/MagicZoomPlus/Model/Observer.php**:

```
class MagicToolbox_MagicZoomPlus_Model_Observer {
    public function fixLayoutUpdates($observer) {
    }
}
```

if you try to create a plugin with command like this:

```
class MyPluginCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, view):
            sublime_api.window_run_command(
                self.view.window().id(),
                'show_overlay',
                {
                    'overlay': 'goto',
                    'show_files': True,
                    'text': 'MagicToolbox/MagicZoomPlus/Model/Observer#fixLayoutUpdates'
                }
            )
```

it will not display the file on first hand. but if you remove all the text from the search input, and then paste it again `MagicToolbox/MagicZoomPlus/Model/Observer#fixLayoutUpdates` it will display the file and highlight the function.

Maybe there is another way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation, it looks like when you provide text to the `show_overlay` it's just applied directly to the contents of the text field and used as a simple filter for initial display without any of the extra handling that would occur if you entered the text manually. Thus when you insert text that includes special goto features such as the `#` that you're using here, it's applied strictly as a filter on the files being displayed but no extra action happens.

As you've noted, opening the overlay and then entering the text as two actions has the desired effect. So in order to do this via a plugin, you need to do this in two actions:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.window().run_command("show_overlay", {
            "overlay": "goto",
            "show_files": True
        })
        self.view.window().run_command("insert", {
            "characters": "Observer#fixLayoutUpdates"
        })
```

Here we first open the overlay and then use the `insert` command to insert the text. The important key here is asking the `window` to run the `insert` command. Although `insert` is a `TextCommand`, asking the `window` to execute it tells the window to forward the command to whatever `view` happens to have the input focus in that window, which is the input area in the overlay.

If the command that you're doing this in isn't modifying the selection or contents of the file on it's own, you can shorten this up by making it a `WindowCommand` instead and using `self.window` instead of `self.view.window()`.

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly. Do you have any idea where I can find more information about the syntax of the **goto** window? there are cases where the **#** does not do what I expect

Comment: I don't think there's any information about it in the [Official Docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/) but the Unofficial Docs have a [page about it](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_navigation.html).